# Assembly - Help me understand the procedure prologue

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, disassembly

Stacks grow from higher memory address to lower memory address, The following code confuses me, in **line #1 esp is copied to the ebp register, in line #3 esp is subtracted by 8**, But **in line #16 the variable is accessed by ebp+8**, could some one explain **why it is not ebp - 8?**

```
(gdb) disass main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
0x08048474 <main+0>:    push   ebp
0x08048475 <main+1>:    mov    ebp,esp
0x08048477 <main+3>:    sub    esp,0x8
0x0804847a <main+6>:    and    esp,0xfffffff0
0x0804847d <main+9>:    mov    eax,0x0
0x08048482 <main+14>:   sub    esp,eax
0x08048484 <main+16>:   cmp    DWORD PTR [ebp+8],0x1
0x08048488 <main+20>:   jg     0x80484ab <main+55>
0x0804848a <main+22>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+12]
0x0804848d <main+25>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [eax]
0x0804848f <main+27>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp+4],eax
0x08048493 <main+31>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x80485e5
0x0804849a <main+38>:   call   0x804831c <printf@plt>
0x0804849f <main+43>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x0
0x080484a6 <main+50>:   call   0x804833c <exit@plt>
0x080484ab <main+55>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+12]
0x080484ae <main+58>:   add    eax,0x4
0x080484b1 <main+61>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [eax]
0x080484b3 <main+63>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
0x080484b6 <main+66>:   call   0x8048414 <function1>
```

Comment: Because that's not a local variable, it's an argument passed via the stack. As such, it's at higher address than even the initial `esp`.

Comment: Ohhhhh Forgot about the function parameters, Thanks @Jester

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For typical 32-bit calling conventions and a typical prologue the values above or at `ebp+08h` are the procedure parameters.

The values below `ebp` are local vars.

The value at `ebp` is the old frame pointer, the value at `ebp+04h` is the return address.

See [the calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions).

Accessing the memory below `esp` (beware: `esp` not `ebp`) is unpredictable but the addresses above are fine (*exactly because* the stack grows downward).
The SYS V x64 ABI define a Red Zone below `rsp` that is fine to use anyway.